# iOS Application launching error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

After updating my ipad os from 8.3 to 8.4..When I run the application from visual studio 2012 it shows the following error:-

> Error 1   error MT1007: Failed to launch the application
>   'com.your-company.RentB' on the device 'MSTech iPad': Look for earlier
>   warnings returned: 0x454. You can still launch the application
>   manually by tapping on it.    Xamarin.iOS Extension   0   0

I am launching this app on iPad (ios 8.4).

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Have you updated XCode and it's tools to the latest version that support 8.4?

Comment: Update all tools you are using and clean your solution in visualstudio. That worked for me

Answer (score 5):

For me, this error turned out to be tied to the [Free Provisioning Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=vsmac) and my physical device no longer trusting it. It stopped trusting it immediately after I deleted the application from my phone. I began seeing the error after trying to debug the app again, which reinstalled the app on my phone but failed to launch.

To tell your device to trust the profile again, navigate to `Settings` -> `General` -> `Device Management`. Under the `Developer App` section, select your provisioning profile, then trust it again.

Within that screen after trusting the app you'll see:

> Apps from developer "iPhone Developer: myProfileName" are trusted on this iPhone and will be trusted until all apps from the developer are deleted.

So, if you ever delete your apps from the physical device, you may run into this again.

I [created a blog post](https://storiknow.com/xamarin-ios-mt1007-failed-to-launch-the-application/) with a bit more detail on how I came to this conclusion.

Comment: Not sure why I keep seeing this as a "solution". "Device Management" isn't even an option in the iPhone settings...

Comment: @pay Device Management is only revealed if you actually have devices or profiles setup. Otherwise, it's hidden. For example, I currently have a "Developer App" installed on my device, which allows me to test my app on this phone. If I delete the app then the Device Management option is no longer visible.